# If f=O(g), there is c>0 s.t. FOR ALL n $\in$ N: $f(n)\le c\cdot g(n)$

Tags: limits, asymptotics, computational-complexity

This is a homework problem, but it's taking me longer than expected to solve so I'd appreciate a direction.

The definition of O(g)=f states that it has to be from a specific point, $n>n_0$, meaning I have to find two functions, where the inequality:

$$f(n)<c\cdot g(n)$$

doesn't hold true, or prove this is true by induction.

I'm thinking this isn't true, because since c has to be a constant, not something that changes, so all it will take is to find 2 functions that can disprove this statement.

EDIT: $f,g: \mathbb N \to \mathbb R ^+$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

What happens if $g(0)=0$ but $f(0) > 0$ ?

**Edit**

If $f$ and $g$ from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb R^+$ then it is true:

- As $f=O(g)$ there exists $c_1>0$ and $n_0$ such that $\forall n > n_0$, $f(n) < c_1 g(n)$.
- With $$ c_2=\max_{n \leq n_0} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$$
  you have $\forall n \leq n_0$, $f(n) < c_2 g(n)$.

Then you can verify that with $c=\max(c_1,c_2)$, you have $\forall n $, $f(n) < c g(n)$.

Comment: Forgot to add that $f,g: \mathbb N \to \mathbb R ^+$